# IntelliJ / PyCharm navigate by Regex

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm a pretty avid user of PyCharm but still having to use Sublime for some things most days and there is always some niggly little things that i find annoying in both. Another one i've just stumbled across not having the ability to regex search navigate File, Class, Symbol etc.

In Sublime i can do `cocbas` and it will give me `templates/cocreate/base.html` but in PyCharm it will just give me nothing found as Sublime matches it to the path.

Is there anyway to get regex searching on paths for File navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your `cocbas` search is not "regex" search.

In intellij, you can search file by pressing ctrl-shift-n, then you can for example:

for file `fooo/bar/blah/IAmHere.html` do `f/b/b/iam` you will see the file in the list, in fact you can just type`iah` the file would be shown in list too.

Comment: Hmm, iah doesn't seem to work but if i do `coc/b` it will only show me the base.html which is what i was after basically. Thanks :)